# What is Model in ModelAndView from Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Having this basic function

```
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(...) {
    ...
    return new ModelAndView("welcomePage", "WelcomeMessage", message);
}
```

I know that this will return modelandView. 
I know that `welcomePage` is my viewname so that means something like `welcomepage.jsp` will get called.

But I am confused with what is Model part. 
What is `WelcomeMessage` and `message` and how Model work in that scenario?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The model presents a placeholder to hold the information you want to display on the view. It could be a string, which is in your above example, or it could be an object containing bunch of properties.

**Example 1**

If you have...

```
return new ModelAndView("welcomePage","WelcomeMessage","Welcome!");
```

... then in your jsp, to display the message, you will do:-

```
Hello Stranger! ${WelcomeMessage} // displays Hello Stranger! Welcome!
```

**Example 2**

If you have...

```
MyBean bean = new MyBean();
bean.setName("Mike!");
bean.setMessage("Meow!");

return new ModelAndView("welcomePage","model",bean);
```

... then in your jsp, you can do:-

```
Hello ${model.name}! {model.message} // displays Hello Mike! Meow!
```

Comment: so it means WelcomeMessage is the variable name to be used in jsp and "Welcome!" . Can you please tell me where i can find what other things the second argument can take like now i understand that it takes variable name , model name , is there any other thing which it can take

Comment: The second argument represents the logical name of your model. You can call it whatever name you want, but this is the name you will use when referencing your model in your JSP. In my first example, I called it `WelcomeMessage`, in the second example, I called it `model`. Use a name that makes sense to you. The third argument holds the information... it could be a simple string, or a POJO or a map... basically any useful information you want to display in the view.

Answer (score 28):

```
new ModelAndView("welcomePage", "WelcomeMessage", message);
```

is shorthand for

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
mav.setViewName("welcomePage");
mav.addObject("WelcomeMessage", message);
```

Looking at the code above, you can see the view name is "welcomePage". Your `ViewResolver` (usually setup in `.../WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml`) will translate this into a View. The last line of the code sets an attribute in your model (`addObject("WelcomeMessage", message)`). That's where the model comes into play.

Answer (score 17):

It is all explained by the javadoc for [the constructor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/portlet/ModelAndView.html#ModelAndView(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)).  It is a convenience constructor that populates the model with one attribute / value pair.

So ...

```
   new ModelAndView(view, name, value);
```

is equivalent to:

```
   Map model = ...
   model.put(name, value);
   new ModelAndView(view, model);
```

Answer (score 14):

Here in this case,
we are having 3 parameter's in the Method namely **ModelandView**.

According to this question, the first parameter is easily understood. It represents the **View** which will be displayed to the client.
The other two parameters are just like **The Pointer** and **The Holder**
Hence you can sum it up like this

**ModelAndView(***View, Pointer, Holder***);**

**The Pointer** just points the information in the **The Holder**

When the **Controller** binds the **View** with this information, then in the said process, you can use **The Pointer** in the **JSP** page to access the information stored in **The Holder** to display that respected information to the client. 
*Here is the visual depiction of the respected process.*

```
return new ModelAndView("welcomePage", "WelcomeMessage", message);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well, WelcomeMessage is just a variable name for message (actual model with data). Basically, you are binding the model with the welcomePage here. The  Model (message) will be available in welcomePage.jsp as  WelcomeMessage.
Here is a simpler example:

```
ModelAndView("hello","myVar", "Hello World!");
```

In this case, my model is a simple string (In applications this will be a POJO with data fetched for DB or other sources.). I am assigning it to myVar and my view is hello.jsp. Now, myVar is available for me in hello.jsp and I can use it for display.

In the view, you can access the data though:

```
${myVar}
```

Similarly, You will be able to access the model through WelcomeMessage variable.

Answer (score 1):

**ModelAndView:** The name itself explains it is data structure which contains Model and View data.

```
Map() model=new HashMap(); 
model.put("key.name", "key.value");
new ModelAndView("view.name", model);

// or as follows

ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
mav.setViewName("view.name");
mav.addObject("key.name", "key.value");
```

if model contains only single value, we can write as follows:

```
ModelAndView("view.name","key.name", "key.value");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register",method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView postRegisterPage(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,
           @ModelAttribute("bean")RegisterModel bean)
   {
       RegisterService service = new RegisterService();
       boolean b = service.saveUser(bean);

       if(b)
       {
           return new ModelAndView("registerPage","errorMessage","Registered Successfully!");
       }
       else
       {
           return new ModelAndView("registerPage","errorMessage","ERROR!!");
       }
   }



/*  "registerPage" is the .jsp page -> which will viewed.
/* "errorMessage" is the variable that could be displayed in page using -> **${errorMessage}**
/* "Registered Successfully!" or "ERROR!!" is the message will be printed based on **if-else condition**
```