# HTTP Status 500 - javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'first_name' not found on type java.lang.String

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jsp

I don't know anymore what is the problem with my code, I am trying to retrieve values from mysql database when certain condition were met and it will display in a table. Here is my code

StudentForm.jsp

```
<c:url var="actionUrl" value="process" />
<form id="student-form" method="post" action="${actionUrl }">
  <select name="column">
    <option>*</option>
    <option>last_name</option>
    <option>first_name</option>
    <option>cp_num</option>
    <option>birthday</option>
    <option>grade</option>
  </select>&nbsp

  <select name="condition">
    <option>=</option>
    <option><</option>
    <option>></option>
    <option><=</option>
    <option>>=</option>
    <option>!=</option>
  </select>&nbsp

  <select id="gradeID" name="grades">//grades have a dropdown list of 50-100
  </select>&nbsp

   <button id=submit>Submit</button><br/><br/>
   </form>

  <table border="1" id="studentTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th align=center>First Name</th>
        <th align=center>Last Name</th>
        <th align=center>Cellphone Number</th>
        <th align=center>Birthday</th>
        <th align=center>Grade</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>

<tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${studentList}" var="student" >
        <tr>
            <td align=center><c:out value="${student.first_name}" /></td>
            <td align=center><c:out value="${student.last_name}" /></td>
            <td align=center><c:out value="${student.cp_num}" /></td>
            <td align=center><c:out value="${student.birthday}" /></td>
            <td align=center><c:out value="${student.grade}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
   </tbody>
```

Student.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student 
{
  private Long sid;
  private String last_name;
  private String first_name;
  private String cp_num;
  private String birthday;
  private int grade;

  @Id
  public Long getSid() 
  {
    return sid;
  }

  public void setSid(Long sid) 
  {
    this.sid = sid;
  }

  @Column
  public String getLast_name() 
  {
    return last_name;
  }

  public void setLast_name(String last_name) 
  {
    this.last_name = last_name;
  }

  @Column
  public String getFirst_name() 
  {
    return first_name;
  }

  public void setFirst_name(String first_name) 
  {
    this.first_name = first_name;
  }

  @Column
  public String getCp_num() 
  {
    return cp_num;
  }

  public void setCp_num(String cp_num) 
  {
    this.cp_num = cp_num;
  }

  @Column
  public String getBirthday() 
  {
    return birthday;
  }

  public void setBirthday(String birthday) 
  {
    this.birthday = birthday;
  }

  @Column
  public int getGrade() 
  {
    return grade;
  }

  public void setGrade(int grade) 
  {
    this.grade = grade;
  }
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/StudentInformation")
public class StudentController 
{
  @Autowired
  private StudentDao studentDao;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/StudentForm")
  public String showForm() 
  {
    return "StudentForm";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/process", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String process(@RequestParam(value="column", defaultValue="") String column,
        @RequestParam(value="condition", defaultValue="") String condition,
        @RequestParam(value="grades", defaultValue="") int grades, Map<String, Object> map)
  {
    map.put("studentList", studentDao.findData(column, condition, grades));
    return "StudentForm";
  }
}
```

StudentDaoImpl

```
@Repository
public class StudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao 
{
  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
  @Autowired
  private Student student;

  private SessionFactory getSessionFactory() 
  {
    return sessionFactory;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public List<Student> findData(String column, String condition, int grades)
  {
    String hql = "SELECT x."+ column +" FROM Student x WHERE x.grade"+ condition +":grades";
    Query query = getSessionFactory().openSession().createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("grades", grades);
    List<Student> result = query.list();

    return (List<Student>)result;
  }
}
```

StudentDao

```
public interface StudentDao 
{
  public List<Student> findData(String column, String condition, int grades);
}
```

error code

```
HTTP Status 500 - javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'first_name' not found on type java.lang.String

type Exception report

message javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'first_name' not found on type java.lang.String

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'first_name' not found on type java.lang.String
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:172)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'first_name' not found on type  java.lang.String
javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:266)
javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$300(BeanELResolver.java:243)
javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:353)
javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:97)
org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:967)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.StudentForm_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fout_005f0(StudentForm_jsp.java:290)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.StudentForm_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(StudentForm_jsp.java:241)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.StudentForm_jsp._jspService(StudentForm_jsp.java:135)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:172)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: rename `first_name` to `firstName` and other such properties and change their accessors

Comment: You need to watch out, this code is prone to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: a new error occurs org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/StudentForm.jsp at line 52

49:  <tbody>
50:    <c:forEach items="${studentList}" var="student" >
51:         <tr>
52:            <td align=center><c:out value="${student.firstName}" /></td>
53:             <td align=center><c:out value="${student.lastName}" /></td>
54:             <td align=center><c:out value="${student.cpNum}" /></td>
55:             <td align=center><c:out value="${student.birthday}" /></td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this in various ways:-

1) Change the last param from `Map<String,Object>` to `ModelMap model`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/process", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView process(@RequestParam(value="column", defaultValue="") String column,
        @RequestParam(value="condition", defaultValue="") String condition,
        @RequestParam(value="grades", defaultValue="") int grades, 
        ModelMap model)
  {
    model.addAttribute("studentList", studentDao.findData(column, condition, grades));
    return "StudentForm";
  }
```

OR

2) Second option is to return `ModelAndView` as per this 
[What is Model in ModelAndView from Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055358/need-help-with-undestand-modelandview-in-java-spring)

Comment: ive tried doing this and replacing all first_name to firstName, last_name to lastName and cp_num to cpNum and still the same error but now it is saying the firstName

Comment: Remove the last part of the JSP the <c:forEach> and try outputting just ${studentList} and check what you get

Comment: great! it is working! but i want to get each of them and to display it in my table.. how am i suppose to do that

Comment: I am suspecting that `${studentList}` in `<c:forEach items="${studentList}" var="student" >` is not available. if you did `<tr><td>${studentList}</td></tr>` you may find out what the value is and help you in debugging.