# Spring: ModelAndView can't locate view

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

This controller fails to find the view "index":

```
@RequestMapping("/test2")
public ModelAndView test2() throws Exception {
    return new ModelAndView("index");
}
```

It returns a 404 error, with the following in the GlassFish console:

```
Severe:   PWC6117: File "null" not found
```

That is strange because this controller finds it ok:

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public String test() throws Exception {
    return "index";
}
```

My project is NetBeans default Spring Web MVC project (using 4.0.1). The only config change is to add this to applicationContext.xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="myapp"/>
```

It seems that either I'm using ModelAndView incorrectly, or for some reason it's using different view resolution.

For reference, this is the view resolver:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

And this is the web.xml for the dispatcher:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: What if you define an attribute to the object of type ModelAndView?

Comment: Sorry @GiancarloAbelGiulian, I don't quite understand what you mean?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Any other details? Are you sure it is hitting the Controller method? 404 usually happens when mapping can't be found

Comment: @jny - I'm sure it hits the controller method - I included a System.out.println statement which is displayed in the GlassFish console. What other details would you like? I can put a zip of the whole project online if you like

Comment: Are those methods located in the same controller?

Comment: @Lukehey - yes they are

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5055390/4088809

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say with no doubt because you didn't post your list of importations of the code, but i think this error (404 not found) occurs when you import "org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView" instead of "org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView" One is used for portlets, the other for servlets. Most of the ide's imports the firs one automaticaly.

Comment: Spot on! That was exactly the problem. Thank-you, I had been totally stuck on this

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was wrong folder name as you know moving project from windows to Linux your WEB-INF folder changes name to lowercase and of course in this case your ModelAndView cant find right path for .jsp files in war and all you need to do is uppercase WEB-INF folder