# how to redirect another jsp page in controller using spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

[in WEB-INF having a Jsp File pls see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp261.png)   **I am using Spring mvc with Hibernate Database connection,in my controller having data from database in variable `val`  now how can i redirect to another jsp page with data's**

Controller Part:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/EditShop" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
          public String editShop(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException 
          {             
              String id=request.getParameter("Id");       
              try
              {     
                  String val=shopService1.editShopinfo(id);
                  System.out.println("Edit Shop : "+val);                         
              }
              catch(Exception e)
              {

                  System.out.println("Edit Shop : "+e );              
              }                    
               return "redirect:/EditShop.jsp";
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass data from controller to UI(another JSP page) with the help of ModelAndView in Spring.

```
new ModelAndView("newJSPPage","aliasNameToBean",originalBean);
```

**newJSPPage** - replace with the new JSP file which you need to redirect from the controller.

**aliasNameToBean** - replace with the alias name which you can access bean data at redirected JSP page.

**originalBean** - replace with the original bean object name which you have the data.

Comment: For more information visit this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055358/what-is-model-in-modelandview-from-spring-mvc

Comment: I add above but In my console page ( output page ) is showing                               DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'EditShop'; URL [/WEB-INF/EditShop.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
DEBUG JstlView - Added model object 'shopModel' of type  [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'EditShop'
DEBUG JstlView - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/EditShop.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'EditShop'          page is dose't forwarding in another page

Comment: Basically, you should not declare JSP files inside the WEB-INF. It should be under WebComponent and outside the WEB-INF. You should be declared redirected file with .jsp if you haven't configured prefix/suffix. Could you please add your code for better understand.

Comment: in my inside of WEB-INF having a jsp file but it not forwarding in another page pls seee above Image  @ Subbareddy Nallamachu

Comment: I am sorry, currently, I am in the office. It's not allowing to open the image link

Comment: Yeah, this is not in spring. Use the concept of RequestDispatcher in servlets. Before forwarding, you set bean request. With the same name, you get the value in JSP page.

Answer (score 0):

return "redirect:/EditShop.jsp";

Insted of this you have return View Name like 
return "EditShop";

In Spring Execution Flow InternalResourceViewResolver will Take Care to Call Jsp.

you have to set **val** to *HttpSession* Object like session.setAttribut("val",valueofField);

Then you get that value In your jsp
session.getAttribute("val");

I Hope it helps.