# Not Returning JSP from Spring Controller

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I need to validate the credentials in the database so I have written a logic to check the given details, that code is working properly for but it's returning and printing the string values instead of returning JSP.

Request you all to help and check what is wrong here.

**Code :**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/adminvalidate")
        public @ResponseBody String validateAdmin(@RequestParam(value="userid",required=true) String userid, @RequestParam(value="password",required=true) String password) {
            String result = loginser.validate(userid, password);
            if (result.equals("pass")) {
                return "redirect:admin/view";
            }
            return "error";
        }
```

Comment: which view resolver are you using?

Comment: <bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>
it was working for remaining all codes in the same controller and as well as other controllers except for this.

Comment: Get rid of `@ResponseBody` and it will work as you wish.

Comment: Thanks alot...it work's can i know reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove @ResponseBody and be specific to use ModelAndView for passing view

```
@RequestMapping(value="/adminvalidate")
public ModelAndView validateAdmin(@RequestParam(value="userid",required=true) String userid, @RequestParam(value="password",required=true) String password) {
            String result = loginser.validate(userid, password);
    if (result.equals("pass")) {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:admin/view");
    }
    return new ModelAndView("error");
}
```

Comment: thank you for your sollution..can i know what exactly modelandview does..?

Comment: ModelAndView is a class where model holds data to be presented in view and view is the jsp(or html ) you want to display ,you can find detailed explanation here -https://stackoverflow.com/a/5055390/7849549

Comment: you can upvote my answer if you find it relevant @Nagendra -Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As conveyed by Piotr Podraza, by removing @ResponseBody your code should work.

If you annotate a method with @ResponseBody, spring will try to convert its return value and write it to the http response automatically.

Hence, either you return a string and redirect to a jsp or use ResponseBody and return the content that you wish to show.